# Java Swing - Adding two panels to a JFrame (side by side)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I have a main frame and in it i have a ScrollPane to which i have added a JPanel.
as such:

```
public class MapFrame extends JFrame{
    public MapFrame() {
            buildTheUI();
            setUpEventHandling();
    
            //consolePanel = new ConsolePanel();
            mapPanel = new MapPanel();
    
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mapPanel);
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setSize(1024, 1024);
            this.add(scrollPane);
            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

The mapPanel Is a map where i display coordinates and looks as such :

```
public class MapPanel extends JPanel{
public MapPanel() {
        Commander.getInstance().addShapeContainer(this);
        mapPanelState = NoState.getInstance();
        MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler(this);
        KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener();

        readImage();

        loadingLabel =  new LoadingLabel();
        this.add(loadingLabel);

        autoUpdateCoordinates(2, 30);

        this.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
        this.addKeyListener(keyListener);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}
```

and these two together look just fine like this.

[image]

Now all i want to do is add another Jpanel within the same scrollPane where i can display some information in a console but when i do it all turns into mush.

The console panel looks like this:

```
public class ConsolePanel extends JPanel {

    private final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    public ConsolePanel(){
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        TextArea console = new TextArea("random info here");
        //console.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        console.setEditable(false);

        this.add(new JLabel("Console"), setConstraints(0, 0, 10));
        this.add(console, setConstraints(0, 1, 10));
        //this.add(closeButton, setConstraints(0, 2, 10));
    }


    public GridBagConstraints setConstraints(int x, int y, int anchor) {
        c.gridx = x;
        c.gridy = y;
        c.anchor = anchor;
        return c;
    }
}
```

but when i simply do a `scrollpane.add(consolepanel)` in the MapFrame class i get no result and only the map shows and if i do a `this.add(consolepanel)` in the same class i get this abomination:
[image]

How can i fix it so they just sit side by side as in the console panel is to the right of the maps and in the same scrollpane ?

Comment: Have you tried using a third panel? By putting console and map in this one, and setting it as the scrollpane content

Comment: usually components are not `add`ed to the scroll pane, it only holds one element in its viewport - see its documentation or the Java Swing [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: You can't do `scrollpane.add(consolepanel)`.  Instead, create a third panel onto which both `mapPanel` and `ConsolePanel` are added to, then use apply it to the `JScrollPane`'s view port view

Comment: ok let me try give me a second. ill update you!

Comment: That worked like a charm thx ladies/gents. ill upp vote all ur comments since all were right.

Comment: Do not pass `10` as an anchor value.  GridBagConstraints has constants for a reason.